# Neither 'day_of_week' nor 'which_occurrence' can be specified when creating a monthly date-based trigger

Tags: puppet

When trying to switch a schedule trigger from a monthly by-weekday schedule to a by-date schedule, I get an error saying 'day_of_week' nor 'which_occurrence' can be specified when creating a monthly date-based trigger.

However, I am not using either of these properties in the new configuration.

```
Error: Neither 'day_of_week' nor 'which_occurrence' can be specified when creating a monthly date-based trigger                     
Error: /Stage[main]/Windowsupdate::Config/Scheduled_task[Run Windows Update]/trigger: change from [  
  {                                                                                                                                     
    'schedule' => 'monthly',                                                                                                            
    'months' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],                                                                                
    'which_occurrence' => 'second',                                                                                                     
    'day_of_week' => ['saturday'],                                                                                                         
    'start_date' => '2018-8-7',                                                                                                         
    'start_time' => '13:15',                                                                                                            
    'enabled' => true,                                                                                                                  
    'minutes_interval' => 80,                                                                                                           
    'minutes_duration' => 560,                                                                                                          
    'index' => 0                                                                                                                      
  }] to [                                                                                                                             
  {                                                                                                                                     
    'schedule' => 'monthly',                                                                                                            
    'start_time' => '13:15',                                                                                                            
    'months' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],                                                                                    
    'on' => 15,                                                                                                                         
    'minutes_interval' => '80',                                                                                                         
    'minutes_duration' => '560'                                                                                                       
  }] failed: Neither 'day_of_week' nor 'which_occurrence' can be specified when creating a monthly date-based trigger
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the scheduled_task module. When I remove the existing task and run the code again, it applies without issue.

Comment: I agree that that sounds like a bug.  I'm sure the Puppet team would appreciate you [reporting it to them](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/projects/MODULES/issues).

Comment: Good idea! For those interested in the progress, a bug has been [created](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-8402)